# Method of characteristics and first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

While solving an PDE using method of characteristics on of the equations I got is:

$$y_t=x+y\Rightarrow y_t-y=x$$

This is a linear first order ODE that can be solve as follow:

$$y_h=c_2e^t$$

Then using variation of parameters should $y_p=c_s(s)e^t$ or $y_p=c_2(t,s)e^t$?

The solution is still $y=y_h+y_p$?

The PDE is:

$$
\begin{cases}
xu_x+(x+y)u_y=1\\
u(1,y)=y\\
\end{cases}
$$

Which I once asked about

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing $x$ and $t$? I cannot understand how you have solved the first ODE.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro added more info, I am trying to solve the ODE using superposition and finding the homogenous and particular solution. I just do not understand how to work with the constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat this equation together with the equation
$$
x_t=x
$$
for $x$ or the coefficient of $u_x$, as alone there is no control on what $x(t)$ is. Now that $x(t)=e^tx_0$ you can solve the original equation
$$
y_t-y=x=e^tx_0\implies (e^{-t}y(t))_t=x_0\implies y(t)=e^ty_0+te^tx_0.
$$

Comment: Where did the $y_t,y$ from $y_t-y=x=e^tx_0$ came from?

Comment: This is the equation that you wanted to solve, I just inserted the solution for $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{cases}
xu_x+(x+y)u_y=1\\
u(1,y)=y\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\frac {dx}{x}=\dfrac {dy}{x+y}=\dfrac {dz}{1}$$
So you need to solve this system of DE:
$$\begin{cases}\dfrac {dx}{x}=\dfrac {dy}{x+y} \\ \dfrac {dz}{1}=\dfrac {dx}{x} \tag{2}\end{cases}$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{x}=\dfrac {dy}{x+y} $$
$$(x+y)dx=xdy $$
$$ydx-xdy=-xdx$$
$$\frac {ydx-xdy}{x^2}=-\frac 1 x dx$$
$$\frac {xdy-ydx}{x^2}=\frac 1 x dx$$
$$d\left (\frac y x \right )= \frac 1 x dx$$
Integrate:
$$ y (x) = x\ln x+C_2x$$
The second one is easy to integrate:
$$\dfrac {dz}{1}=\dfrac {dx}{x} \tag{2}$$
$$z+C_1=\ln x$$
You can surely take from there.